# How does connected speech work for accents which use the "h" sound?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, accent

Consider a British accent which doesn't use the "h" sound, so for example "hair" is pronounced /ɛə/ or /ɛː/.

When we say "your hair", do we pronounce the "r"? Do we say /jəɹɛə/?

Another way of phrasing my question: does silent "h" in spelling change anything when it comes to using connected speech?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to copy the dropped 'h' (this kind of dialect detail can develop naturally in your accent, but it isn't something to be learnt)

However, in British English dialects, when the 'h' is dropped, the word then starts with a vowel, and so intervocalic 'r' will be pronounced to give something like /jɔːɹɛə/. In British dialects (including RP) with a pronounced 'h' one gets /jɔːhɛə/

The actual quality of the vowel in "your" is quite variable both in different dialects, and from utterance to utterance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Don't try to copy the dropped 'h'"? What's the worst that might happen?

Comment: If you try to drop your 'h' deliberately it will sound fake and unnatural.  You won't seem like a skilled English speaker, nor will you seem like a local Londoner (or other region in which the 'h' is dropped)   You will sound like a weird foreigner who is doing a funny but fake accent.  Now, if you naturally acquire the dropped 'h', after a long time living in London, that is different, that is natural language acquisition. But don't try to "learn it from a book", the worst that can happen is that you will offend someone who thinks you are ridiculing their dialect.